# Get a certain number of contiguous rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've got a school project, kind of huge, and only a few days left, so here is one problem I'm stuck on, hope you can help.
I've got this table:

```
places(id, otherInfo)
```

Simple enough, well I need to make a SQL query or PL/SQL function to retrieve a certain number of contiguous rows. For instance if I call the function using `getContiguousPlaces(3);` On the table which has the rows:

```
ID
1
4
5
6
18
19
```

I want to get rows with `ID` 4, 5 and 6.

How could I do that?

Comment: pl/sql is kind of easy, but the sole query yes is tricky :-)

Comment: What results would you expect if you called getContiguousPlaces(2)? I am not sure I understand what the argument you pass into that function specifies.

Comment: @justin
I pass the number of contiguous places I need.

Comment: For the `ID=[4,5,6,7]` and `getContiguousPlaces(2)` what would be the result? Is it `[4,5], [6, 7]` or `[4,5], [5,6], [6,7]`?

Comment: What should be the result if you called `getContiguousPlaces(4);` on your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.prev_id1, p.prev_id2
FROM (
        SELECT id, LAG(id, 1) OVER(ORDER BY id) prev_id1, LAG(id, 2) OVER(ORDER BY id) prev_id2
        FROM places
     ) p
WHERE p.prev_id1 = id-1 
AND   p.prev_id2 = id-2
```

here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a20e1/1

But I guess you could retrieve the datas differently if you wished.

edit: this case if for the parameter "3". But if you want to adapt it with a number "n", you either have to use it within a dynamic query, or maybe use the partition by clause. I'm going to have a look at this one now...

Comment: And what if the source data contains also a row with `id=7` ?

Comment: the query returns 4 5 6 and 5 6 7

Comment: Thanks a lot, really.
Don't worry about dynamic queries, I'll do a PL SQL procedure with  a dynamic cursor.
If it is doable, how would I do to get the best solution even if I don't have enough contiguous places? Like if I have ID 1,4,5,6,9,18,19 and i do getContiguousPlaces(4), how to return 4,5,6,9 ?
By the way this is for a camping management program, I got to get contiguous spaces for groups of campers.
Thanks again for your fast and great answers

Comment: actually I came up with something else. I'm going to try it in a little while. for your secondary question i don't know, really...

Comment: ups somebody else found it out^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH t AS
  (SELECT p.*, LEVEL l,
                     CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS cbr
   FROM places p CONNECT BY
   PRIOR id = id-1)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE cbr IN
    (SELECT cbr
     FROM t
     WHERE l = 3 )
and l <= 3
ORDER BY cbr,
         id
```

The constant 3 should be a parameter

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa884/14) is a fiddle